# Why drag and drop does not work on my Mouse-Down Right Click?

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, contextmenu

The follwoing code refuses to work for drag and drop on the right mouse click.  When I right click the mouse I do see the proper context menu but I am not able to drag and drop although  I do have an event handler for DragDrop , DragEnter, and DragOver. Is it because I can't have context menu and drag and drop on the same right click?  what am I doing wrong?  Your help is very much appreciated.

```
private void treeList1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TreeList tree = sender as TreeList;
    Point pt = tree.PointToClient(MousePosition);
    TreeListHitInfo info = tree.CalcHitInfo(pt);

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && ModifierKeys == Keys.None && tree.State == TreeListState.Regular)
    {
        if (nodeType == typeof(X))
        {
            tree.ContextMenuStrip = XContextMenu;
            tree.FocusedNode = info.Node;
            treeList1.AllowDrop = true;
            tree.AllowDrop = true;
        }
        currentFocusNode = tree.FocusedNode;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the **[DoDragDrop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx)** method.

Here is an [example](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2007/07/07/basic-drag-and-drop-in-winforms/) of using DragDrop

In your example, add something like this before the `return;`

```
treeList1.DoDragDrop(currentFocusNode, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added what you mentioned. Now I do see a chnage, I do see a cirlce with a line across it.  Before your change I was not seeing  that.  But what is the circle with a diameter drawn across it ?  what else I am not doing?

Comment: Did you try playing with the example I linked to?

Comment: Thank  you again. Very helpful example. I will mark  your answer as the answer. Please if you have any other good URL with explanation about DragDropEffects's different enumeration meanings and AllowedEffect meanings please list it for me,  Immensly grateful for your answer.

Comment: Two more tutorials you might like are [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9017/A-Simple-Drag-And-Drop-How-To-Example) and [this one](http://tech.pro/tutorial/753/winforms-using-custom-cursors-with-drag-drop)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how can you do a dragDrop on to listView for example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.AllowDrop = true;
    listView1.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(listView1_DragDrop);
    listView1.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(listView1_DragEnter);
}

void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(e.Data.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I already had marked the answer , but thank you anyway. I have a question about the meaning of all the  DragDropEffects values such as copy/link/Move.  I will post it as a separate question if you dont feel inclined to answerme here, but I do not understnad the difference between all these values.  Thanks

Comment: Drag enter is when you move a file with mouse to a windows. Drag drop is when you move it to a window and release a mouse button.